# Minimizing the Memory Used

Tags: c++, pointers, memory

i got a doubt, as we know that Pointer is a variable that stores address.
Can i store a Value at that address using

```
cin>>(*p);
```

without using any other normal variable.
Code Below explains the same:

```
#include'iostream'
int main()
{
    long long *p;
    cin>>(*p);
    cout<<(*p);
    return 0;
}
```

Is it right to store variable like that?

If we could store value like this then we can save so much of memory, because we only pointer variable has to be assigned the memory. Which is far less than the size of Normal long long data type.

Comment: Your understanding of pointers is very misleading. Spend a week on reading several good books. And in practice you have a *lot* of memory. The point is not to save it, but to use it wisely.

Comment: using a pointer would actually use *more* memory because of the space needed for the `long long` (often 8 bytes) *and* the value for the pointer (often 4 or 8 bytes)

Comment: This kind of coding does not save memory, usually makes the code worse, and is a total waste of time.

Comment: @vu1p3n0x but all the pointer variable occupy same amount of memory. Not 8bytes it occupy 4 bytes, it depends on machine too.
As far as i know.
please correct me, if i'm wrong..

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Can you suggest me any book or video tut. to get my concept crystal clear in Pointers.
Thannks!

Comment: one most basic thing to note: it's #include <iostream>

Comment: @ZhouZhiHua i wrote that first but it wasn't showing the "<iostream>"...
so i simply put single quote so that it's visible which header file i included...
i thought it'll be understood to everyone.
i should have use 'code' attribute..

Comment: @HarimangalPandey try the book im reading by joyce farrell about Object Oriented Programming though its a 2009 version I think but still can be used today

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The pointer has an undefined value, hence any attempt to write at that address will result in undefined behavior.

Better:

```
int main()
{
    long long *p = new long long();  // heap allocation
    cin>>(*p);
    cout<<(*p);
    delete p;
    return 0;
}
```

OR

```
int main()
{
    long long p;  // stack variable
    cin>>p;
    cout<<p;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Using `new` is only better in the sense that at least it's not UB, but of boy I wouldn't recommend showing that to someone who is so obviously a complete beginner.

Answer (score 2):

[image: hope this explains better]
Hope this picture explains better.

The left column uses following code :

```
int main() {
    long long p;
    std::cin >> p;
    std::cout << p;
}
```

is using a `long long p` to store data, it allocate eight bytes space for `p` and release that memory when the program is finished.

The right column is using your code(I made a bit of change/)

```
int main() {
    long long *p = new long long();
    std::cin >> *p;
    std::cout << *p;
    delete p;
}
```

It allocate 4 bytes for pointer on a 32 bit machine, or 8 bytes for pointer on a 64 bit machine. When you use a pointer, it must be allocated a memory location for it to store data, so it will allocate another 8 bytes of memory on the heap for the long long type. So the later one uses more memory.

For better memory efficiency, you should just stick with `long long p`, avoid pointers, plus the thing that allocating and deallocating memory for pointer is slow.

Comment: Also you must not forget about `delete` otherwise the memory will leak. Better yet, use a smart pointer. Even better, don't mess with pointers at all.